# Finding expected value of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let *n* and *m* be fixed natural numbers, and let N, X1,X2,... be independent random variable such that *N ~Po(n)* and *Xk ~Po(m)* for all *k*. Set $S_N$ = $$\sum_{k=1}^N X_k $$ assuming $S_0=0$. Find $E(S_N)$

I have no idea how to handle with this question. Since it goes from 1  to N. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the *Law of Iterated Expectations*: $~\mathsf E[S_N]~=~\mathsf E\big[\mathsf E[S_N\mid N]\big]$

We have: $~\mathsf E[S_N\mid N{=}p]~=~\mathsf E\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^p X_k\right] ~=~ \sum\limits_{k=1}^p \mathsf E[X_k]~=~p~\mathsf E[X_1]~=~p~m$

Thus: $~\mathsf E[S_N\mid N]~=~N~m$

Finally: $~\mathsf E[S_N]~=~\mathsf E[m~N]~=~m~\mathsf E[N]~=~m~n$

Note that we could have done the same kind of proof with other distributions than Poisson.